# Help in interpreting chkrootkit analysis for MS Teams package

Tags: security, chkrootkit, microsoft-teams

I run from time to time a `chkrootkit` to make sure my install does not get infected. Today I ran it while MS team was on (I need to use it for my classes).
Here is what I found:

```
Checking `chkutmp'...
The tty of the following user process(es) were not found in /var/run/utmp !
! RUID          PID TTY    CMD

! ted-code-mitigations
0 -id=6  --shared-files=v8_snapshot_data:100 --msteams-process-type=notificationsManager
! ent-id=4
0 n-frame-before-activation --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_snapshot_data:100 --msteams-process-type=mainWindow
! tron-site-instance-overrides
0 derer  --num-raster-threads=2 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=9 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_snapshot_data:100 --msteams-process-type=experience-renderer
! =v8_snapshot_data:100
0 usted-code-mitigations --msteams-process-type=pluginHost
```

Any expert analysis/advice beyond "Don't use this Microsoft/evil corp. software"?

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing in the output outside of this utility enmity towards some strings.

There are currently zero good utilities in Linux to detect the presence of malware. `chkrootkit` and `rkhunter` are both jokes which can identify some simple pieces of malware but if someone wants to specifically target you, you're SoL, especially considering that most Linux users eschew running with Secure Boot on because it makes using third-party Linux drivers either impossible or a chore.